# How to get the device Id while doing integration testing in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutterdriver

I am trying to get the device Id inside app_test.dart file. But i am getting the following error. while executing the following command: flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart.

Please find the error details below:

```
I/flutter (20622): Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:43149/9iUskIArAjk=/
../../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/semantics/semantics.dart:2121:39: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'List<SemanticsNode>' which excludes null.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'SemanticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/semantics/semantics.dart' ('../../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/semantics/semantics.dart').
    for (int position = 0; position < childrenInDefaultOrder!.length; position += 1) {
                                      ^
lib/utility/colors.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui';
       ^
../../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/app.dart:33:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
export 'dart:ui' show Locale;
^
../../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:7:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui show Image, ImageFilter, TextHeightBehavior;
       ^
../../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show AppLifecycleState, Locale, AccessibilityFeatures, FrameTiming, TimingsCallback;
       ^
../../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart:24:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
export 'dart:ui' show AppLifecycleState, Locale;
^
../../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/bottom_navigation_bar_item.dart:7:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show Color;
       ^
../../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/color_filter.dart:7:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui';
       ^
../../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui hide TextStyle;
       ^
../../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/focus_manager.dart:8:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui';
       ^
../../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/focus_traversal.dart:7:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui';
       ^
Stopping application instance.
Driver tests failed: 254
```

Comment: Also interested in this, we investing a lot of time into flutter_driver tests which have been broken for a while now since the null safety update

Answer (score -1):

This issue is related to referencing flutter code from your target script. You simply can't do that: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27826

You can use `requestData` from Flutter driver to communicate between your target and driver code, and get the required value in your target script. More here: https://www.kabisa.nl/tech/extending-flutter-driver-with-custom-commands/